# I'm using Crypto++ for RSA encryption. My plain text exceeds FixedMaxPlaintextLength. What should I do?

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

Should I break the text into chunks?

Is RSA the wrong encryption scheme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrong scheme. The standard technique for message encryption (for example, PGP and CMS) is to generate a random symmetric session key K for something like AES and encrypted the message with AES using key K. Then encrypt K with the public key of each recipient of the message.

Comment: Yes, especially because RSA encryption is very slow compared to symmetric key algorithms like AES. 
Use RSA to establish a shared key and use that one to encrypt your actual data.

Comment: You've left out one **crucial** step, which is to pad K with a secure padding scheme - like OAEP from PKCS#1 - before encrypting it with RSA.  Crypto++ provides OAEP as an "Asymmetric Cipher Encoding Method".

Comment: I left out *all* the crucial steps.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the asymmetric RSA algorithm is used for key exchanges.  If you are encrypting larger chunks of data, it might be better to use something like AES.